# Crash due to water bottle

Tags: road-bike

I have a little bit of a unique question here. 
Does anyone know of a cycling crash that was caused due to the cyclist drinking out of his/her water bottle?

Comment: Essentially, you're asking a question to which the answer is an unboundedly long list of incidents. There have surely been cases where pros have crashed this way; there have surely been cases where somebody's mate at the club has crashed that way; there have surely been cases where people riding on their own have crashed that way. There might even be some famous incidents but no answer could ever be comprehensive and it's hard to say that one answer is better than another.

Comment: For these kinds of reasons, [list questions are generally discouraged on Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: I've seen someone fail to put a bottle back in the cage, dropped it in a bunch, and those behind had to swerve to avoid.  I was at the end and ended up riding over his bottle and it would have thrown me if I hadn't been ready.   So yes, its totally possible.

Comment: I bet there have been crashes caused by ringing the bell.  VTC

Comment: I'm sure I've read of such a case. I don't follow sports so unless it was here it was in the general news. So a major event like a grand tour or the Olympics, and/or a top British rider

Answer (score 1):

When I used to ride in a paceline a lot, I had a lot of issues with getting a drink of water while maintaining a straight line. So much so, those riding in the paceline complained. Since then, if I'm riding in a paceline, I wait until I'm at the end of the paceline to get a drink. With practice, maybe this would be less of an issue for me. If you're racing, maybe waiting until you're at the back isn't so much an option but in those situations you have to be very cautious when drafting anyway.

Comment: A lot has to do with the cage (and the bike).  I raised my cage several inches because it was too low to reach without looking.